# android how to remove space on the left and right side of listView item - redefine listPreferredItemPaddingStart?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to have ListView witout some space before (on the left) and after the item (on the right) (it's the space which is added inside item, it's quite visible if you have set item divider, it's wider that item text contents). It seems it cannot be done with padding neither layout_margin.

As far as I understand [Android code listview style definition](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) I have to modify the following attributes:

```
android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
```

I was sure that in my theme I can simply write:

```
<item name="android:paddingStart">0dip</item>
<item name="android:paddingEnd">0dip</item>
```

But then unfortunately I have to set min sdk to 17 which seems not be worth to set such a high value just because of that small thing.

How to remove this space on the left and right side of listview item (and still have code for all sdk versions (or at least 14 and highers).

Moreover I've tried the code above with emulator for sdk 18 and it doesn't seem to work (still have space inside item).

Any help?

Comment: I know this is old question but if some one has same problem can try with  -ve Left Padding and it does not show the left spaces. android:paddingLeft="-10dp"

Answer (score 1):

Create two different layouts, one for newer api, and one for older api. `layout-17` and `layout` folders

in the old api just use `paddingLeft = 0` and `paddingRight = 0`. and in the new api, use the method you suggested.

Comment: How to make that my new attributes (values equal to 0) will be applied only to all ListView elements and not to others?

Comment: And what about other solutions nulling left and right space for items? Creating two layouts for each screen plus two themes doesn't seem to be the perfect idea... a lot of work...

Comment: Some times its the best approach using different layout for different APIs, you set the paddingLeft and paddingRight in the xml